# Pasar parámetros a un servidor HTTP en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Buen dia. Soy nuevo en programacion de node js y tengo un ejemplo en para conectarme por ssh a un servidor remoto, este ejemplo tiene la direccion ip de manera estatica o definida pero, me gustaria pasarle la direccion ip por url con metodo GET o desde un formulario en HTML a la cual conectarse. Intente con URL y get pero no logre que funcionara, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(onRequest);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var SSHClient = require('ssh2').Client;
var url = require('url');
var sys = require('sys');
qs = require('querystring');

// Load static files into memory
var staticFiles = {};
var basePath = path.join(require.resolve('xterm'), '..');
staticFiles['/xterm.css'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, '../css/xterm.css'));
staticFiles['/xterm.js'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, 'xterm.js'));
basePath = path.join(require.resolve('xterm-addon-fit'), '..');
staticFiles['/xterm-addon-fit.js'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, 'xterm-addon-fit.js'));
staticFiles['/'] = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

var parametros=[];
function onRequest(req,res){
  var file;
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    file = staticFiles[req.url]
    console.log("Si se cumple");
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/'
        + (/css$/.test(req.url)
        ? 'css'
        : (/js$/.test(req.url) ? 'javascript' : 'html'))
    });
    return res.end(file);
  }
  console.log("no se cumple");
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
}




let port = 8083;
console.log('Listening on port', port)
server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta llega un poco tarde, pero sé que te va a ser útil.

Antes de empezar, te quiero dar un par de consejos que me habría gustado mucho que me dieran cuando yo empecé en esto. Si no te interesa, sáltatelo.

Si quieres ir directo al grano, revisa los archivos `controller/setServerIp` y `routes/main`.

- **Sepáralo todo.** No juntes el proceso principal con el servidor, las rutas, los controladores, las vistas, etc. Un código fragmentado es más fácil de leer y mantener. Todas las funciones que se repitan y puedas separar del controlador, a la carpeta helpers. Si puedes evitar manejar los errores desde el mismo controlador, evítalo.
- **Todo lo que pueda ser una constante, declárala como tal.** Las dependencias se suelen declarar como constantes porque no van a cambiar su contenido. Si una propiedad dentro de una función no va a cambiar, no uses ni `var` ni `let`, usa `const`. **Que no te engañen los arrrays y objetos, estos pueden ser constantes aunque sus valores cambien.**
- **Basa tu servidor en objetos**, crea una clase e instánciala dentro de otro archivo separado. No lo hagas en el archivo del punto de entrada ni en otro al que suelas acceder regularmente, corres el riesgo de producir dependencias circulares y es un jaleo solucionarlas cuando el proyecto ya ha crecido.
- **Aprende a controlar la asincronía**, al principio se le tiene respeto, cuando la conoces eres tú quien manda en esto.
- **Olvídate de los callbacks**, usa promesas y ejecútalas en su lugar con `async/await`, si necesitas más control ya sabes, `then` y `catch`.
- **Aprende a usar funciones de flecha.** `() => { }` funciona casi igual que `function(){ }`, salvo en casos especiales, te será más cómodo/rápido declarar funciones de esta forma.
- **Usa una buena estructura de carpetas**. Como te he comentado, fragmenta todo tu código, crea una carpeta llamada `server` para almacenar la instancia del servidor, otra llamada `models` para el modelo del mismo y todas las clases que vayas a declarar, `routes` para las rutas, `controller` para controlar cada petición, `middlewares` para autenticar, validar o hacer cualquier cosa antes de llegar al controlador, `helpers` para todo el código que se repite en los controladores, si vas a servir archivos estáticos (una página), usa la carpeta `public`.

Espero que estas pocas buenas prácticas te sirvan.

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, vamos al lío:

### Declarar la clase del servidor (models/server.model.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const { Main } = require('../routes/main.routes');

class Server {

    server = express();
    port;

    constructor(port = 3000) {
        this.port = port;
        this.load();
    }

    routes(){
        // Esto carga el archivo de rutas principal.
        this.server.use('/', Main);
    }

    middlewares() {
        // Esto para leer datos desde el cuerpo.
        this.server.use(express.json());
    }

    load(){
        this.middlewares();
        this.routes();
        this.start();
    }

    start() {
        this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto ${this.port}.`);
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Server;
```

### Rutas (routes/main.routes.js)

```
const { setIpServer } = require('../controllers/setServerIp.controller');
const Main = require('express').Router();

Main.get('/server/:ip', setIpServer);

// Esto envía los archivos estáticos.
Main.use('/', static(`${process.cwd()}/backend/public/`));
// Esto es por si usas Angular, para que sea cual sea la ruta no pierdas referencia.
Main.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${process.cwd()}/backend/public/index.html`));

module.exports = { Main };
```

Observa la ruta de la 4ª línea, fíjate donde pone `/:ip`, eso es el parámetro, es lo que el servidor espera como dato.

Cuando navegues a `localhost:2000/server/192.168.1.2`, el servidor recogerá este último fragmento (`192.168.1.2`) y podrás trabajar con ello.

### Controlador (controllers/setServerIp.controller.js)

```
const { request, response } = require('express');

const setIpServer = (req = request, res = response) => {
    // Coge la dirección IP del parámetro (esto viene del router).
    const IP = req.params.ip;
    // Esto ya es trabajo tuyo, la constante IP tiene tu dirección...
    console.log(IP);
}

module.exports = { setIpServer };
```

### Instancia del servidor (server/http.server.js)

```
const Server = require('../models/server.model');

let httpServer;

const loadServer = (port) => {
    httpServer = new Server(port);
}

module.exports = { httpServer, loadServer };
```

Observa como aquí he usado let, esto es para que al acceder al archivo, no se vuelva a crear una nueva instancia, si quiero acceder a un método del servidor, sólo tengo que cargar la variable `httpServer`, si quiero iniciar el servidor, cargo `loadServer`(y si quieres, le pasas un número como parámetro para arrancarlo en un puerto específico)

### Archivo principal (index.js)

```
const { loadServer } = require('./server/http.server');

const main = () => {
    loadServer(2000);
}

main();
```

Ejecuta `npm i express` y arráncalo con el comando `node .` o `node index.js`.

Abre un navegador y dirígete a `http://localhost:2000/server/192.168.1.2`. Revisa la consola y ahí deberías tener tu dirección IP.

Espero que esto te sirva tanto a ti como a cualquiera que lo lea.

Casi se me olvida, esta estructura se trata del MVC (modelo-vista-controlador). Para quien le interese, [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93controlador) hay una referencia directa a él en Wikipedia.

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te agradezco el tiempo que te tomaste en explicarme y los consejos que me diste, de verdad muchas gracias. Tomare en cuenta todos los consejos que me diste y son buenas bases para tomar en cuenta a la hora de programar. Te mando un saludo y nuevamente muchas gracias..